# Qt 5.9.1 windows MSVC2015 STATIC project linking error

Tags: visual-studio, qt, static

I am trying to build qt-based project using MSVC2015 with QT 5.9.1 built as -MT static library (build with MSVC2015 and jom). I am getting linking error:
unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher"

Here is the list of linked libraries:

Mincore.lib Version.lib qtpcre.lib qtmain.lib Ws2_32.lib    qtharfbuzz.lib Qt5Core.lib Qt5Gui.lib Qt5OpenGL.lib opengl32.lib    glu32.lib Qt5Widgets.lib Qt5PlatformCompositorSupport.lib    qwindows.lib Imm32.lib qtfreetype.lib Winmm.lib qico.lib    Qt5Network.lib Qt5Svg.lib qtlibpng.lib Qt5Xml.lib Qt5Sql.lib    Qt5Multimedia.lib UxTheme.lib Qt5ThemeSupport.lib    Qt5FontDatabaseSupport.lib Qt5AccessibilitySupport.lib Dwmapi.lib    qdirect2d.lib

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

missed Qt5EventDispatcherSupport.lib.